# what is the equivalent of mysqli_fetch_array for prepared_statement?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

im trying to get the string of a simple cell from a table.
iv done that like this(without preparing statements):

```
if($result_ur = mysqli_query($conn_ur, $sql_log)) {
    /* this is the problem */

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_ur);

    /* here finishes my problem*/

    $lvl = $row['lvl'];
    $nombre = $row['nombre'];

    $username =$row['username'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    /*blablablabla more variables*/

    echo $username." <br>".$email."<br>";


    mysqli_free_result($result_ur);
    //-- ELSE DE NUM ROWS
```

it works like a charm! but now iv read about sql injections so a friend told me that (for security reasons) i could do it by "preparing statements", so i can evade the injection.

im REALY lost iv done all iv read and nothing...
my server dont allow get_result(); so im binding results like this

```
<?php 
    include dirname(__FILE__)."/conect_reg.php";

    $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
    echo "variable ".$nombre.", working?<br>";
    if($nombre) {
        $checkuser = $conn_reg->prepare ("SELECT * FROM  `usus` WHERE `usuario` =  ?");
        $checkuser->bind_param("s", $nombre);
        $checkuser->execute();                  
        $checkuser->store_result();                 
        $checkuser_rows = $checkuser->num_rows; 

        /* Here is the problem */   
        if($checkuser != 0) {                   
            $checkuser_res = $checkuser->bind_result($id_d,$nombre_d,$paterno_d,$materno_d,$usuario_d,$pass_d,$email_d,$lvl_d,$telefono_d,$fecha_d,$code_d,$active_d,$profileimg_d);
            return $checkuser_res;
            $row = fetch($checkuser_res);
          /*  Here finish the problem    */
        }   
    }

    echo "working?<br>";

?>
```

it works up to "bind_result", (being honest i dont know what im doing, im just like that meme of the dog with the pc).

what i need is to use the equivalent of `echo $row['user']; like mysqli_fetch_array

or

```
if ($row['user'] = $user){
    echo "that ";
}
```

but i dont know how to make that with "preparing statements" and "bind_result".
Edited: making question more comprehensive.

Comment: I don't use `mysqli` but from my readings here and on the manual... The `bind_result` only `Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.`. The call assigns the values to the variables in the function, I also thought you still had to `fetch`. You are doing the `return` before the `fetch`. Might want to look over http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: thaks chris in the manual you send they make a "while" to fetch the result, then they "print" like list, how i can get a value of a single cell and then store it in a variable? like "$row['user']"

Comment: If there is only 1 row you don't need the `while` just call the `fetch`. You then can return the `$row` array, or send back the one value, `$row['user']`, assuming you have a column named `user` and `fetch` to the `$row`.

Comment: yes its only one row, so i need to fetch before return.
just $row = fetch($checkuser_res); ? then $row['whatevercolumn']; ?

Comment: The [`bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) call assigns `$row['user']` to a variable in the order of the `SELECT` statement columns. e.g. `$checkuser = $conn_reg->prepare ("SELECT user FROM usus")` then `$checkuser->bind_result($user)` then `$checkuser->fetch()` then `$user` will be the equivalent of `$row['user']`

Comment: fyrye iv done that but i get this mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement, is this caused cause my table have 13 colums ? this is my code now:


$nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
if($nombre) {   $checkuser = $conn_reg->prepare ("SELECT * FROM  `usus` WHERE `usuario` =  ?");
  $checkuser->bind_param("s", $nombre);
$checkuser->execute();     
$checkuser->store_result();     
$checkuser_rows = $checkuser->num_rows;     
if($checkuser != 0) {$checkuser->bind_result($usuariod);
 echo $usuariod; } }

Comment: Be explicit to the columns you're after in your `SELECT` statement. Remove the `*` and specify the columns you are wanting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) call assigns `$row['user']` to a single variable in the order of the `SELECT` statement columns, as opposed to the array form you've used with `mysqli_fetch_array`.

The equivalent functionality would be as follows:

```
$checkuser = $conn_reg->prepare ("SELECT `id`, `nombre`, `paterno`, `materno`, `usuario`, `pass`, `email`, `lvl`, `telefono`, `fecha`, `code`, `active`, `profileimg` FROM `usus` WHERE `usuario` =  ?"); 
$checkuser->bind_param("s", $nombre);
$checkuser->execute();
$checkuser->bind_result($id_d,$nombre_d,$paterno_d,$materno_d,$usuario_d,$pass_d,$email_d,$lvl_d,$telefono_d,$fecha_d,$code_d,$active_d,$profileimg_d);
if ($checkuser->fetch()) {
    echo $usuario_d . " Hello";
}
```

Comment: This is what i was trying get explained, so the bind_result its "equal" to the mysqli_fetch_array!